# Subsetting data on number of observations between unique combination of variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as such:

```
descriptionin = c("sample1","sample1","sample1","sample1","sample1","sample1","sample1","sample1","sample2","sample2","sample3","sample3","sample3","sample3","sample3","sample3")
dilutionin = c(1,10,100,1000,1,10,100,1000,5,5,2,8,32,2,8,32)
conditionin = c("cond1","cond1","cond1","cond1","cond2","cond2","cond2","cond2","cond1","cond2","cond1","cond1","cond1","cond2","cond2","cond2")

testin <- data.frame(descriptionin,dilutionin,conditionin)
```

and would like to subset the dataframe to this:

```
descriptionout = c("sample1","sample1","sample1","sample1","sample1","sample1","sample1","sample1","sample3","sample3","sample3","sample3","sample3","sample3")
dilutionout = c(1,10,100,1000,1,10,100,1000,2,8,32,2,8,32)
conditionout = c("cond1","cond1","cond1","cond1","cond2","cond2","cond2","cond2","cond1","cond1","cond1","cond2","cond2","cond2")

testout <- data.frame(descriptionout,dilutionout,conditionout)
```

To explain, I would like to subset the dataframe by each unique description/condition combination that has more than a number (in this case 1 but the actual data set will be 3) of dilutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(testin)`), grouped by 'descriptionin' and 'conditionin', we find the row index (`.I`) of elements in the group that have more than one `unique` 'dilutionin' and use that index to subset the rows

```
library(data.table)
setDT(testin)[testin[, .I[uniqueN(dilutionin)>1], .(descriptionin, conditionin)]$V1]
```

Comment: Thanks! I get everything in this but the $V1?

Comment: @AwesomeeExpress  By using `.I`, a column is created with default name as `V1' which contains the row index, we extract that column by `$V1` and use it to subset the rows of dataset

Comment: Got it! Thanks again